# How to programmatically align elements in a Stackview using SnapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, snapkit

I'm trying to achieve a specific design inside a custom reusable view.

(Something like this: )

[image]

So I pass an URL to retrive the image and I pass a String to add below.

Firstly, I want the entire view to be the width of the elements (if the text is long then the entire view will be wider), I don't know how to do that, the view seems to be the entire width of the screen.

Secondly, I want the items to be centered horizontally and vertically, what I tried does not work.

Here is my current code :

```
func initLayout() {
        stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        stackView.distribution  = UIStackView.Distribution.fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
        stackView.spacing   = 10.0

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textContainer)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(stackView)
        self.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(70)
        }
        self.stackView.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
    }
```

And it results in something like this:
[image]

As you can (or cannot) see, the view is centered in the middle of the screen, which is not what I want. The view should be the width of the text and everything centered inside this particular width, then I add it inside my VC and place it so it's leading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand well the is your constraint **without** Snapkit:

Set your objects under your class controller declaration:

```
let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Débats"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .semibold) // set your font size here
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()
```

Now in viewDidLoad set parameters and constraints:

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilo") // set here your image
    
    let myWidth = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width // This reveal only text width in label
    
    view.addSubview(myLabel)
    myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: myWidth).isActive = true
    myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

This is the result:

[image]

Intere code:

```
class Aiutotipo: UIViewController {

let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Débats"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .semibold)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilo") // set here your image
    
    let myWidth = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width // This reveal only text width in label
    
    view.addSubview(myLabel)
    myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: myWidth).isActive = true
    myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```